# Why can't I maximize Settings window?

Tags: settings, release-hera, window-management

Every time I open System Settings it won't let me maximize the window and part of it strangely hidden below (!) the screen, so I can't reach some of the settings (like the "Apply" button). Clicking on "Maximize" button or using keyboard shortcuts doesn't work. I can't even change height of the window. Need help!
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Removing "elementary-tweaks" package helped.

Answer (score 0):

this happens to me too, but I do not understand the solution well, are you saying that you have to uninstall the elementary-tweaks package ?, because removing said package you do not have the option to minimize.

Thank you.

Greetings.